# Simplify Matrix math code- Sun billboarding

Tags: xna, monogame, matrix, optimization, billboarding

If was trying to set the correct position of my sun billboard in my 3d game. I tried long until it worked correctly, but I wonder why this code must be so complicated:

```
sun.sprite.Position = Vector3.Transform(Vector3.Transform(-sun.lightDir, 
Quaternion.Inverse(world.Rotation)), Quaternion.Inverse(myRelativeRotation));
```

Can I simplify this expression? I tried changing it at least to this:

```
sun.sprite.Position = Vector3.Transform(-sun.lightDir,
Quaternion.Inverse(world.Rotation) * Quaternion.Inverse(myRelativeRotation))
```

But this is giving me different results, so the sun is at the wrong position.

Comment: Have you tried reversing the order of multiplication of the quaternions in your second example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found a solution and made it even simpler:

```
sun.sprite.Position = Vector3.Transform(-sun.lightDir, 
    Quaternion.Inverse(myRelativeRotation * world.Rotation));
```

Because according to [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixInverse.html) explanation is:

```
A^-1 * B^-1 = (B * A)^-1
```